SwiftUI: There are unwanted margins in the widget
enter is hereI'm trying to create a widget using SwiftUI with a LinearGradient background. While the gradient stretches vertically, there are unwanted margins on the left and right sides. I’ve used GeometryReader and .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height) to ensure it fills the widget area and applied .ignoresSafeArea(), but the issue persists. How can I make the gradient cover the entire widget without margins? Using containerRelativeFrame solves my issue, but it only supports iOS 17+. My goal is to make this work for iOS 16+.
struct ExampleWidgetEntryView: View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            let colors = BackgroundColors.randomTwoColors()

            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                Color(colors.color1),
                Color(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)),
                Color(colors.color2)
            ]), startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomLeading)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height) // Make the gradient fill the widget
            .ignoresSafeArea() // Ignore safe areas

            VStack {
                Text(entry.message)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1.0)))
            }
        }
        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height) // Ensure ZStack fills the entire widget
    }
}

}

See Medium Widget Size Background Image or Color not filling the entire space

From iOS 17 onwards, use containerBackground to set the widget's background. You can remove the ZStack:
VStack {
    Text("Some Message")
        .font(.system(size: 18))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255))
}
.containerBackground(
    .linearGradient(colors: [.red, .white, .blue], startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomLeading),
    for: .widget
)

Your existing code will work as expected on iOS 16 and before, so if you want to also support iOS 16, simply add an if #available.
let widgetBody = VStack {
    Text("Some Message")
        .font(.system(size: 18))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255))
}
if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
    widgetBody
        .containerBackground(
            .linearGradient(colors: [.red, .white, .blue], startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomLeading),
            for: .widget
        )
} else {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
            .red,
            .white.opacity(0.8),
            .blue
        ]), startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomLeading)
        widgetBody
    }
}

